Is it possible for `latexmk` to output the values of its configuration variables?
To avoid falling into the XY problem, it might be helpful to provide some clarification and motivation. My root LaTeX file is main.tex in the project root directory, and I would like to use a .latexmkrc file that initialises $jobname, $aux_dir and $out_dir, among other configuration variables. I have no problem with the latexmk build, but I have not managed to make it play nicely with TeXstudio, which has a built-in Latexmk command. In particular, running the TeXstudio build command creates the correct files in the $aux_dir and $out_dir directories. However, the TeXstudio internal viewer expects main.pdf in the project root directory. There is already an option to override this with the PDF path, but I would like to do this programmatically instead of changing it in the editor settings when switching between projects.
The -rc-report can be passed to Latexmk to report the path of read rc files, which is in the same direction but not exactly what I am looking for. Hence, the question:

Is there any option that can be used to report (some of) the values of parsed configuration variables, preferably without building the document?

Since latexmk already parses its initialisation files, asking TeXstudio maintainers to repeat the process would not be ideal. If latexmk could output the values of $jobname and $out_dir, it should not be too much work to get TeXstudio to read them.
As you may have gathered by now, the main goal is to be able to use TeXstudio and have a tidy project folder. So, if you happen to be aware of an alternative method to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's how to configure latexmk to do a selective output of the variables you are interested in, and to put the result in a format that's convenient for your purposes.
The trick is to use latexmk's variable $compiling_cmd to cause execution of a chosen subroutine at the start of each compilation.  A possible solution is:
$compiling_cmd = "internal show_config";
sub show_config {
   print "=======================\n",
         "Latexmk settings:\n",
         "Jobname = '$jobname'\n",
         "Aux_dir = '$aux_dir'\n",
         "Out_dir = '$out_dir'\n",
         "Out2_dir = '$out2_dir'\n",
         "=======================\n";
}

This displays the variables you are interested in.  (I've put lines consisting of the equal signs before and after the message block to make the results easy to locate.)  You can easily modify this code to suit your exact needs.
Note that I've added a display of the name of the "final-output directory".  This is a new feature in recent versions (4.84 and above) of latexmk, that I find useful in some cases.

Dear Prof Collins, thank you for your helpful answer. For my specific settings, I have simplified the command to the following:
latexmk -e 'print \"final-output:$out2_dir/$jobname.pdf\"; exit 0;'
so that I get the pdf filename in a dry run without changing the .latexmkrc file.

In addition to TeXstudio, I have also run into an issue when using the forwardSearch method of the texlab LSP server, which also comes down to expecting the wrong PDF filename. The above answers my question in my current settings, but, as you know, it's more involved in general, e.g. when either $out2_dir/$out_dir or $jobname is not set or a different output format is used. It would be helpful for interoperability with other tools if latexmk could support an option, say -output-report-only, that reports the final output relative path in a dry run and a general setting.

I've just remembered there's an option -dir-report-only, which reports the directories and exits, which I think does what you want.  I'll update it to include $jobname, which seems useful in this context.

Thank you! Yes, including $jobname would be helpful. I appreciate it.

Actually, I realized that it's better to output the base name of the generated files rather than $jobname itself, since that is what one is actually interested in.  Note that latexmk has extended the definition of $jobname to allow a substitutable placeholder %A in it, and one is typically wanting to use the value after substitution.

I was not aware of the substitution. Indeed, the base name is more relevant here than $jobname. In fact, the full path would be more convenient if it’s not too much trouble to output it instead, so one does not need to query the value of $do_cd and treat $do_cd = 1 differently.

Actually, the message in the current version already gives the current working directory, including the effect of any change in directory caused by $do_cd.  So there's enough information available, in principle.  I didn't change that in the new version. As for the basename, it's preferable not to add the path to it, since different generated files go in different directories.   But it might be worth adding the absolute paths for the directories.
